# React Native - Schedule Local Notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, local-notification

Estou utilizando a biblioteca [*React Native Push Notifications*](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) para agendar notificações, mas estou enfrentando um problema que não sei se é possivel resolver com essa lib.

Tenho que agendar uma notificação que se repita toda semana em dias da semana especificos.

No github esse código é disponibilizado para agendar notificações:

```js
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
  message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
  date: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)) // in 60 secs
});
```

E essa seção diz como fazer repetir as notificações:

> Repeating Notifications (optional): Specify repeatType and optionally repeatTime while scheduling the local notification. Check the local notification example above.
>   Property repeatType could be one of week, day, hour, minute, time. If specified as time, it should be accompanied by one more parameter repeatTime which should the number of milliseconds between each interval.

Mas não sei como utilizar isso para repetir apenas em dias especificos da semana, como apenas na terça e na quarta.

Alguem saberia como fazer isso?

Comment: Eu tenho uma ideia mas não sei se funciona e não tenho como testar... Na função `PushNotification.configure` tem a propriedade `onNotification` que é uma função que recebe a notificação, acho que é possível criar uma nova nesse callback de acordo com a data atual, ou seja, você agenda uma notificação, quando for criada, é agendado a próxima e assim por diante. Mas é só uma ideia não sei se vai funcionar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cria uma notificação para cada dia:

```
// toda terca a partir de hoje, essa hora
d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (2 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
  message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
  date: d,
  repeatType: 'week',  
});

// toda quarta a partir de hoje, essa hora
d2 = new Date();
d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + (3 + 7 - d2.getDay()) % 7);
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
  message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
  date: d2,
  repeatType: 'week',  
});
```